# Export from Access to Excel, Bosnian char š not showing completely

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-access, character-encoding

I hope this is the right StackExchange forum for my question. I need to export a table from Access to Excel. It has all sorts of special characters in it. Ranging from é, à, ù to ß and finally š.

All the other characters get through fine, except for š. The thing is, it doesn't show in the Excel Tables, but when clicking on a cell, it shows fine in the input field above the cells.

Any idea how to get this right? I know it's a Bosnian character (http://www.thesauruslex.com/typo/eng/enghtml.htm), but I have no idea which coding I should use to cover all the special characters..

Hope you guys encountered something similar or could guide me to the right solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a font problem. Presumably, the transport has copied font settings. Check ou which font is in use in the cell. Select a cell – the font name should then appear as the selected one in a dropdown in the Start pane, in sufficiently new versions of Excel. Then select some other font in that dropdown, e.g. Arial Unicode MS. If this helps, you might consider setting the font in all cells to the same.

The letter “š” is used in several languages, and it is usually present in Microsoft fonts. But some special fonts (e.g., fonts designed to cover ISO Latin 1 only) may lack it.